# sir i'am trying to call Intent.SEND lower version get this following Exception and higheer version not getting following Exception

Tags: android

sir i'm trying to call Intent.SEND Activity some devices not get this following error and some devices gettting this Runtime Exception how can solve it please support means lower devices not support this intent

**Exception**

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

**Code**

```
try{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    i.setType("text/*"); 
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getData(ref.getAdapterPosition())); 
    context.startActivity(i); 
}catch (Exception e){ 
    Toast.makeText(context,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

Constructor

```
Recycler_Adapter(Context con,int signal){ 
    this.context=con; 
    this.signal=signal; 
    status_add(); 
    dataBinder=new DataBinder(context); 
}
```

as regarding to Exception we already passed the context

**code for passing Context**

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new Recycler_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), signal));
```

Comment: I would guess that you're passing the wrong `Context` in the `Adapter` constructor call. It needs to be the `Activity`, not `getApplicationContext()`, nor `getApplication()`, nor `getBaseContext()`, etc.

Comment: but sir insted of ABOVE code we are using Toast.makeText(context,"hello java..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ///IT WILL SUCCESFULLY RUN no Error .

Comment: how can solve this please help me sir..

Comment: The restriction stated in the given Exception message does not apply to `Toast`s, on any Android version. I've already mentioned that the solution is to pass the `Activity` as the `Context` in the `Adapter` constructor call. And that's not the solution for just this issue. You should always be using the `Activity` for any `Adapter`.

Comment: @MikeM. instead just provide the code example.

Comment: @MikeM. as you know he is passing the wrong context you can see third code block i edited. You will find he is passing `Application Context` while setting the adapter. It should be closed cause there are lots of example

Comment: @Ashish Ah, yeah, I didn't notice the edit. I'm on a really small screen.

Comment: @MikeM. Close the question as Debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide activity context. Just make change with `Activity_name` to your Current Activity

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new Recycler_Adapter(Activity_name.this, signal));
```